# Definite integral with respect to one variable after cross derivative

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

Just want to confirm, it holds that $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial y}dy=\frac{\partial f(x,b,z)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f(x,a,z)}{\partial x}$, right?

This seems right to me as intuitively the "anti-partial-derivative" with respect to $y$ should look like this: $\int\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial y}dy=\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}+u(x,z)$. Thanks!

Comment: I give $1$ sufficient condition. Let $x_0,z_0$ fixed. Let $F:y\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y,z_0)$ be a function of one variable $y$. If $F$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$ then your assertion should be true.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes sense.